# How to create USER DEFINED EVENTS in ALLEGRO 5

Tags: c, allegro5

I am working on a game in allegro 5 in which I want to create rectangular objects dynamically on screen and make them clickable with mouse buttons

```
al_register_event_source( event_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
al_register_event_source( event_queue, al_get_mouse_event_source());

al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
al_flip_display();

al_start_timer(timer);

while ( !exit )
{
    ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
    al_wait_for_event( event_queue, &ev);

    if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
    ;
    else if ( ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_AXES )
     {
       x = ev.mouse.x;
       y = ev.mouse.y;
     }
    else if ( ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_DOWN )
     {
       if ( x >= rect.x && x <= rect.maxx && y >= rect.y && y <= rect.maxy )
             destory ( rect );
     }
    else if ( ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE )
        break;
    if ( redraw && al_event_queue_is_empty(event_queue)){
        redraw = false;
        al_draw_rectangle ( rect.x, rect.y, rect.maxx, rect.maxy, blue, 1 );
        al_flip_display();
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

But this is hardcoded for only one rectangle. How can I make an event for this which can handle rectangles like button.

Comment: How is `rect` defined? Why do you need new event types? Can't you just have a array of rectangles which you loop through when clicking the mouse?

Comment: rect has just its coordinates top x,top y, bottom x, bottom y. I want rectangles on screen randomly and don't want to fix the number of rectangles by using an array of rectangles. But I will try your idea first , it seems good. But how can I determine which rectangle is clicked ? I have to use a big loop but i want an efficient way.

Comment: 1.) Use can use dymanic memory management, and increase array size when it is too small. (Search for `realloc`). Another option is linked lists. 2.) Simplest way to find rectangle is single big loop. If you need something more advanced, you may have to search for *space partitioning*.

Comment: Thanks for your good advice. Can you give me an intro of space partitioning ?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I'm not expert on that. Go with the simple method first. If it's too slow, then look for partitioning, because things will get more complex and difficult.

Answer (score 1):

User events aren't needed to respond to button presses.

Rather, you should approach this from a different angle. Pass the `ALLEGRO_EVENT` to your button class and have it return whether it was clicked or not.

```
bool Button::ButtonPressed(ALLEGRO_EVENT ev) {
   if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_DOWN && ev.mouse.button == 1) {
      if (our_area.Contains(ev.mouse.x , ev.mouse.y)) {return true;}
   }
   return false;
}
```

BUT, you asked how to create user events in Allegro 5 so I will answer that as well.

See https://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/events.html#allegro_user_event for details and a code example. Basically, you create and initialize an `ALLEGRO_EVENT_SOURCE`, register it with your event queue, and then listen for messages you emit with `al_emit_user_event`.